# angularjs: requireing and using tabsetCtrl.select

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-tabset

I am trying to create a directive that will automatically activate angular-ui tabs based on routes.
my directive is intended to be added to every tab element within the tabset.

I am requiring

```
require:['rwActiveIfState','^tabset']
```

and in my compile function I am returning a linking function which begins like this:

```
return function LinkingFunction(scope, element, attributes,controllers) {
      controller=controllers[0];
      tabsetCtrl=controllers[1];
...
```

The `tabsetCtrl` is the controller for the tabset as intended.

I want to call the `.select` method of the `tabsetCtrl`

Its code looks like this:

```
  ctrl.select = function(selectedTab) {
    angular.forEach(tabs, function(tab) {
      if (tab.active && tab !== selectedTab) {
        tab.active = false;
        tab.onDeselect();
      }
    });
    selectedTab.active = true;
    selectedTab.onSelect();
  };
```

And I am calling it by passing the scope parameter that I am getting in my linking function,

From looking at the code of tab and tabset I know the tabset expects the `selectedTab` to be the scope of the tab directive.

This can be seen from the fact that the tab is calling `tabsetCtrl.addTab(scope);` and the `tabsetCtrl` then adds the scope to its tabs collection.

```
  ctrl.addTab = function addTab(tab) {
    tabs.push(tab);
...
```

The tab control calls  but I am not sue how to reach it. 
I was assuming this is the same scope as that of the tab control because my directive is applied to the tab element.

My Q is how do I get to the same instance of the scope that is sent to the tabsetCtrl by the tab from my own directive that is added to the tab attribute ?

NOTES:

1) I used to think that this is exactly the same scope that I get for my directive's linkingFunction but if that was the case I do not understand why I am getting an error in the line for `selectedTab.onSelect();` saying that "undefined is not a function" [i.e. that selectedTab which is the scope of my directive does not have an "onSelect" which If I understand correctly the the scope for the tab should have based on its deceleration of its *isolated* scope which looks like this:

```
   scope: {
      active: '=?',
      heading: '@',
      onSelect: '&select', //This callback is called in contentHeadingTransclude
                          //once it inserts the tab's content into the dom
      onDeselect: '&deselect'
    },
```

2) Maybe this is also related to the fact that the tab directive is also defined as `transclude:true` but again - I am not sure exactly how.